# How to manage order by in SQL server as compare to Sybase?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sybase

I'm migrating from SybaseIQ to SQL Server 2008, one major diffrence observer is in ORDER BY clause.
Created on table as `create table test(name varchar(20))`

Inserted some records:

```
insert into test values('Hi')
insert into test values('Toi')
insert into test values('>Toi')
insert into test values('iHh')
insert into test values('hi')
insert into test values('IhH')
insert into test values('1Hi')
insert into test values('2Hi')
```

Performed select operation on both SQL Server and Sybase as:

```
 select * from test order by name desc
```

Result for Sybase is:

```
name    
------- 
iHh     
hi      
Toi     
IhH     
Hi      
>Toi    
2Hi     
1Hi
```

And result for SQL server is:

```
name    
------- 
Toi     
IhH     
iHh     
Hi      
hi      
2Hi     
1Hi     
>Toi
```

Why this order differ in SQL server and Sybase? How to manage order by in SQL server as compare to Sybase to get same result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the collation [`Latin1_General_BIN2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx) as the SQL server default collation or use the specify collation for the `ORDER` clause.

> **Binary collations**
>
> Binary collations sort data based on the sequence of
>   coded values that are defined by the locale and data type. They are
>   case sensitive. A binary collation in SQL Server defines the locale
>   and the ANSI code page that will be used. This enforces a binary sort
>   order. Because they are relatively simple, binary collations help
>   improve application performance. For non-Unicode data types, data
>   comparisons are based on the code points that are defined in the ANSI
>   code page. For Unicode data types, data comparisons are based on the
>   Unicode code points. For binary collations on Unicode data types, the
>   locale is not considered in data sorts. For example,
>   Latin_1_General_BIN and Japanese_BIN yield identical sorting results
>   when they are used on Unicode data.
>
> There are two types of binary
>   collations in SQL Server; the older BIN collations and the newer BIN2
>   collations. ***In a BIN2 collation all characters are sorted according to
>   their code points.*** In a BIN collation only the first character is
>   sorted according to the code point, and remaining characters are
>   sorted according to their byte values. (Because the Intel platform is
>   a little endian architecture, Unicode code characters are always
>   stored byte-swapped.)

```
declare @Test table (name varchar(20) collate Latin1_General_BIN2)
insert @Test values ('Hi'), ('Toi'), ('>Toi'), ('iHh'), ('hi'), ('IhH'), ('1Hi'), ('2Hi')

select * from @Test order by name desc
```

Or just

```
select * from @Test order by name collate Latin1_General_BIN2 desc
```

Comment: Current database collate is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`, case sensitivity and accent sensitivity required for other database request

Comment: @Pravin You can use the specify collation for the ORDER clause

Answer (score 0):

Use **ASCII Value** for column and order by it in **Descending** order. ASCII will order your first later of word then you can apply order on your column

```
SELECT Name FROM @tblTest ORDER BY ASCII(Name) desc,Name
```

**Output in Descending:**

[image]

**Output in Ascending:**

[image]

Comment: The sort order cannot be determine by `ASCII` correctly as it just return the code of left most character

Comment: it works for op requirement as i have tested in my system, so I have give answer